# How to test AWS Network Load Balancer using Curl command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ecs

I have created an AWS Network Load Balancer, with TCP:80 (HTTP) listener. This listener forward requests to a Target Group called "My-TargetGroup."

I have created a Task Defintion, that points to a Docker Image of the Spring Boot service, that runs on port 8080. In ECS, When I created the ECS Service I selected "My-TargetGroup", with listener port at 80.

I can see that my ECS Service has one Task running successfully. However, I do not know how to test whether NLB is able to forward the request to the underlying spring boot service. For eg. in my Spring boot API, I have a the endpoint myapi/faq. How do I call this API through curl?. Basically, I will be calling this API end point as http/https method. So I want to now test this API as a get call through https protocol

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `netcat` command for a variety of connectivity tests. Here is the syntax

```
nc -v {host} {port}
```

With -v(verbose) option, you should ideally see an output if your server socket returns something on connection.

Answer (score 1):

Before curl, I will suggest making the sure thing on the infrastructure side, cur l will never help you to debug the issue. `curl` may work in your case but normally network Load balancer work on netwrok layer so you can try with `telnet`.

```
telnet lb_endpoint 80
```

But what you need is to make sure is the target healthy?

[image]

So if the target is healthy application is running and LB should response and if not then check security group of LB.

If the target is unhealthy something wrong with ECS services so do need to debug LB.

Comment: I tried with telnet command, but I see the message "Trying <Ipaddress>". I do not get any response. It is stuck.

Comment: did you check the target group health? some thing wrong with LB or either target group

Comment: stuck mean ALB not reachable or the port not expost, also check LB  secuirty group

Comment: Please note that this question relates to NLB and not ALB. There are big differences between both the load balancers. NLB does not have security group. If NLB is not reacheable, then how is the health check not working?

Comment: Oh sorry , NLB use the target security group. so check the target security group

Comment: Could you please clarify what is target security group. The security group of EC2 has correct entries, due to which the health check is working. I couldn't understand "target security group"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199621/discussion-between-kurioz7-and-adiii).